# Telerik RadControl for WPF. Changing MainWindow theme

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, telerik, rad-controls

Is It possible to change the main form theme?
In RadControl for WinForms changing theme also affects on the Form theme (e.g. window header(title) and close(maximize) buttons.

What i have now in WPF:
[image]

What I'm having now in WinForms:
[image]

Comment: [Did you not do a simple search to find out how Telerik does theming in WPF applications?](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/common-styling-apperance-setting-theme-wpf.html)

Comment: @Will The result of this manual can be found on my first screenshot. I mean that It changes only components theme (e.g., in screenshot number one I used ExpressionDark theme), but not the Window theme.

Comment: Aaah, clarification.  Not sure, in that case.  They may not, although there isn't any real reason, as you can theme a window's chrome in WPF just like anything else.  Yep, [the docs don't list the Window as part of themes](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/common-styling-themes-mscontrols.html).  So you can't do this, unless you do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer: It's necessary to create RadWindow instead of Window if i wanna use radControl features. Here's two links with all the information about creating RadWindow:
http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/wpf/window/radwindow-as-main-window.aspx
http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radwindow-features-working-with-radwindow.html